# Apache 2.4 mod_macro does not instantiate all the defined Macros

Tags: macros, apache2

I'm using Apache 2.4 with `mod_macro`. According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html), it is possible to instantiate several macro, in order to not to rewrite the same block of configuration. Example from the documentation:

```
<Macro VHost $name $domain>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName $domain
    ServerAlias www.$domain

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/$name"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/$name.error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/$name.access_log" combined
  </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use VHost example example.com
Use VHost myhost hostname.org
Use VHost apache apache.org
```

I did the same for my server, with the following `VirtualHost` configuration file

```
<Macro VHost $request_uri>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        DBDriver mysql
        DBDParams "host=localhost port=3306 user=myself pass=myselfpass dbname=apacheauth"
        DBDMin  2
        DBDKeep 4
        DBDMax  10
        DBDExptime 300

        <Location $request_uri>
          AuthName $request_uri
          AuthType Digest
          AuthDigestAlgorithm MD5
          AuthDigestDomain /
          AuthDigestProvider dbd
          AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT MD5(password) FROM password WHERE username = %s AND realm = %s"
          Require valid-user
        </Location>

    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use VHost /test
Use VHost /anothertest
```

The prolem is that the configuration work when I try to access `www.mysite.com/test`, asking me for the credential, and does not work when I try to access `www.mysite.com/anothertest`, showing me the current page without asking the credential. It seems like the server instantiates a `VirtualHost` only for the first Use directive, skipping all the following.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with mod_macro, but with the vhosts themselves. If you expand them out by hand, you get this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost port=3306 user=myself pass=myselfpass dbname=apacheauth"
    DBDMin  2
    DBDKeep 4
    DBDMax  10
    DBDExptime 300

    <Location /test>
      AuthName /test
      AuthType Digest
      AuthDigestAlgorithm MD5
      AuthDigestDomain /
      AuthDigestProvider dbd
      AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT MD5(password) FROM password WHERE username = %s AND realm = %s"
      Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost port=3306 user=myself pass=myselfpass dbname=apacheauth"
    DBDMin  2
    DBDKeep 4
    DBDMax  10
    DBDExptime 300

    <Location /anothertest>
      AuthName /anothertest
      AuthType Digest
      AuthDigestAlgorithm MD5
      AuthDigestDomain /
      AuthDigestProvider dbd
      AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT MD5(password) FROM password WHERE username = %s AND realm = %s"
      Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

You have two vhosts listening on the same IP address (`*`) and port (`:80`) and no `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` to distinguish requests. When a request comes in, Apache will load the first matching vhost, so the second vhost is never run.

The use of `<VirtualHost>` inside the macro is just an example, you can generate whatever block you want. It looks like what you actually wanted was a macro for defining the restricted directories:

```
<Macro ProtectDirectory $request_uri>
    <Location $request_uri>
      AuthName $request_uri
      AuthType Digest
      AuthDigestAlgorithm MD5
      AuthDigestDomain /
      AuthDigestProvider dbd
      AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT MD5(password) FROM password WHERE username = %s AND realm = %s"
      Require valid-user
    </Location>
</Macro>
```

You would then have a single vhost with this macro expanded twice inside it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost port=3306 user=myself pass=myselfpass dbname=apacheauth"
    DBDMin  2
    DBDKeep 4
    DBDMax  10
    DBDExptime 300

    Use ProtectDirectory /test
    Use ProtectDirectory /anothertest
</VirtualHost>
```